# How do I optimize the amount of coins in a piggy bank?

Tags: java, math

So in a piggy bank class i have four variables: `pennies`, `nickels`, `dimes`, and `quarters`. If my user inputs three `nickels`, I would like to convert it into 1 `dime` and 1 `nickel`. I know this is an easy problem but I'm just stupid right now. Here is my existing:

```
public void optimize() { //This whole method is 100% terrible.
    nickels = nickels + pennies/5;
    pennies -= (nickels*5);

    quarters = quarters + nickels/5;
    nickels -= (quarters*5);

    dimes = dimes + nickels/2;
    nickels -= (dimes*2);
}
```

Comment: I "think" you could use some modular maths to do it...

Answer (score 3):

```
public void optimize() {
  int total = (25 * quarters) + (10 * dimes) + (5 * nickels) + pennies

  quarters = (total/25); //note the integer division
  total = total % 25; //no more quarters, cut off 25 until we're less than 25

  dimes = (total/10);
  total = total % 10;

  nickels = (total/5);
  total = total % 5;

  pennies = total;  
}
```

Seems like something along those lines should work.

Comment: So that's working now but here's something:             System.out.println((pennies + (nickels * 5) + (dimes * 10) + (quarters * 25))); prints out 0. What happened?

Comment: You're trying to print an `int`. This should work: `System.out.println(Integer.toString(pennies + (nickels * 5) + (dimes * 10) + (quarters * 25)));` if all the variables are `int`s.